# Project Euler question 36

Tags: python

I'm up to [question 36](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=36) and I thought this would be simple. As usual, I am apparently wrong. I'm trying to do this in Python (because I don't know Python). My code is below. I'm getting 19 as the output, which is apparently incorrect. I don't see what I'm missing. Any suggestions (without correcting the code) would be appreciated. I don't want the correct answer or the code (or even an exact location of my error) - just a hint to get me in the right direction.

```
 def isPolynomial(number):
    if(str(number) == str(number)[::-1]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def isBinaryPolynomial(number):
    binNum = bin(number)
    binStr = str(binNum)[2:]
    revbinStr = binStr[::-1]
    if(binStr == revbinStr):
        return True
    else:
        return False
count = 0
for i in range(1, 1000001):
    if isPolynomial(i):
        if isBinaryPolynomial(i):
            count += 1
print count
```

Comment: Just curious, how long does that thing take to run?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference here, but the question asks for numbers LESS than 1,000,000. Your range includes 1,000,000.

Comment: `sum([x for x  in range(1000000) if str(x)==str(x)[::-1] and bin(x)[2:]==bin(x)[:1:-1]])`

Comment: Note that you can simplify your if statements in function returns by simply returning the test. i.e., `return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]`

Comment: @Blindy - I didn't time it, but maybe 1-2 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your code is correct, but you need to read carefully what it asks you to submit as the answer.  I can't be any more specific without giving it away!

Answer (score 1):

From  http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=36

Find the **sum** of all numbers, less than one million, which are palindromic in base 10 and base 2.

Comment: LOL! Wow. I can't believe I missed that. I also think I may need to account for a situation like 110 in binary, which I'm guessing I need to account for leading zero when reversed.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for the sum of the numbers, not the count. Also this does not make a difference in the answer you get, but the word is "Palindrome", not "Polynomial"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's what I get for rushing. My stupidity knows no bounds and I deserve a down vote!

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
@author: neo
"""
def bin(x):
    result = ''
    x = int(x)
    while x > 0:
        mod = x % 2
        x /= 2
        result = str(mod) + result
    return result
print sum(i for i in xrange(1,1000001)\
    if str(i)==str(i)[::-1] and str(bin(i))==str(bin(i))[::-1])
```