# Better Solution to Project Euler #36?

Tags: algorithm, binary, decimal

Project Euler [problem 36](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=36) states:

> The decimal number, 585 = 1001001001 (binary), is palindromic in both bases.
>
> Find the sum of all numbers, less than one million, which are palindromic in base 10 and base 2.
>
> (Please note that the palindromic number, in either base, may not include leading zeros.)

There is already a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6458060/1172169) to this on stack overflow, but I want a *more efficient solution*.

For example, since the palindrome cannot have leading 0's, no even numbers need to be checked, only odd numbers for which the last bit in binary is a 1. This simple observation already speeds up the brute force "check every number in the range" by a factor of 2.

But I would like to be more clever than that. Ideally, I would like an algorithm with running time proportional to the number of numbers in the sum. I don't think it's possible to do better than that. But maybe that is not possible. Could we for example, generate all palindromic decimal numbers less than one million in time proportional to the number of decimal numbers satisfying that property? (I think the answer is yes).

**What is the most efficient algorithm to solve this palindrome sum problem?** I would like to consider run-times parameterized by N: the size of the range of numbers (in this case 1 million), D: the set of decimal palindromes in the range, and B: the set of binary palindromes in the range. I hope for a run-time that is o(N) + O( |D intersect B| ), or failing that, O(min(|D|, |B|))

**Note:** The sequences of [binary](http://oeis.org/A006995) and [decimal](http://oeis.org/A002113) palindromes are well known.

e.g. binary palindromes < 100: 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 15, 17, 21, 27, 31, 33, 45, 51, 63, 65, 73, 85, 93, 99

. . .decimal palindromes < 100:0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99,

palindromes in both bases: 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 33, 99

The binary representations of 33 and 99 are `10001` and `1100011` respectively.
The next number which is a palindrome in both is `585 = 1001001001`.

Comment: To give another example of what I mean, in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374622/project-euler-problem-1-possible-refactorings-and-run-time-optimizations we try to optimize problem 1, summing all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. The straightforward solution takes O(size of the range) to solve it, but the clever solution given by mbeckish solves it in constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of palindromes in base `b` of length `2*k` is `(b-1)*b^(k-1)`, as is the number of palindromes of length `2*k-1`. So the number of palindromes not exceeding `N` in any base is O(sqrt(N))¹. So if you generate all palindromes (not exceeding `N`) in one base and check if they are also palindromes in the other base, you have an O(sqrt(N)*log(N)) algorithm (the log factor comes from the palindrome check). That's o(N), but I don't know yet if it's also O(|D intersect B|).

It's not O(|D intersect B|) :( There are only 32 numbers up to 10<sup>10</sup> which are palindromic in both bases. I don't see any pattern that would allow constructing only those.

¹ If `N` has `d` digits (in base `b`), the number of palindromes not exceeding `N` is between the number of palindromes having at most `d-1` digits and the number of palindromes having at most `d` digits (both limits inclusive). There are `(b-1)*b^(k-1)` numbers having exactly `k` digits (in base `b`), of which `(b-1)*b^(floor((k-1)/2)))` are palindromes. Summing gives the number of base-`b` palindromes with at most `k` digits as either `2*(b^(k/2)-1)` (if `k` is even) or `(b-1)*b^((k-1)/2) + 2*(b^((k-1)/2)-1)` (if `k` is odd). Hence, give or take a factor of `2*b`, the number of palindromes with at most d digits is `b^(d/2)`. Thus the number of palindromes not exceeding `N` is roughly `N^0.5`, with a factor bounded by a multiple of the base considered.

Comment: O(|D intersect B|) means that you would only generate palindromes that are a palindrome in both bases, and use constant time to generate each palindrome.

Comment: Yes, the question was how many numbers are palindromes in both bases.

Comment: Can you clarify in your answer where the sqrt(N) comes from? I believe it stems from the fact that the number of digits is `log_b(N)` (plus or minus 1), and the maximum number of digits a palindrome could be is also `2k`

Comment: It comes from the fact that only half of the digits can be chosen freely, the other half is determined by palindromicity, see update.

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain that O(|D intersect B|) isn't possible, but O(sqrt(N) log N) is much more satisfying than O(N)

Comment: Yes, proving that O(|D intersect B|) is impossible would be very hard. It's plausible that one would need at least a `log N` factor for construction/verification, though. But at the moment, I can't even strictly prove that `sqrt(N)` isn't O(|D intersect B|), it's just extremely unlikely given the growth rate so far (looks like |D intersect B| is O(log N), but that's a guess too).

Answer (score 3):

Consider that there are only about 2000 decimal palindromes between 1 and 1000000.  From 1 to 999, you can string the number and its reverse together, both with and without duplicating the "middle" digit (the last digit of the left part).  For each of those, you check whether it's also a binary palindrome, and if it is, it's part of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

*(not an answer to your question but a cute recursive bit-fiddling solution to Project Euler 36)*

This may not be the most efficient algorithm but I like how it looks like.  I wrote it after reading *Daniel Fischer*'s answer, suggesting to generate all palindromes in one base and then checking in the other base if it's a palindrome too.

In 18 lines of code (including the brackets) it generates all the palindromes in base 2 and then checks if they're also palindrome in base 10.

Takes about 6 ms on my system.

This can probably be optimized (too many bitshifting operation to my taste, there's probably quite some unnecessary junk here) and there may be a better algo, but I "like" (+) the look of my code ; )

```
@Test
public void testProjectEuler36() {
    final int v = rec(1, 1);
    assertEquals( 872187, v );
}

public static int rec( final int n, final int z ) {
    if ( n > 1000000 )
        return 0;
    if ( z % 2 == 0 ) {
        final int l = n << 1 & -1 << z / 2 + 1;
        final int r = n & -1 >>> 32 - z / 2;
        return v(n) + rec( l | 1 << z / 2 | r, z + 1 ) + rec( l | r, z + 1 );
    } else
        return v(n) + rec( n << 1 & -1 << z / 2 + 1 | n & -1 >>> 31 - z / 2, z + 1 );
}

public static int v( final int n ) {
    final String s = "" + n;
    boolean ok = true;
    for ( int j = s.length(), i = j / 2 - 1; i >= 0 && ok; i--)
        ok = s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j-(i+1));
    return ok ? n : 0;
}
```

Comment: (+) when I say that I "like" it, it's in a *"I'm glad I won't have to re-read nor maintain this"* ; )

Answer (score 0):

My first assumptions were entirely wrong, so I've fixed them up. I've provided two algorithms, one iterative and one recursive. They're obviously nowhere near as impressive and efficient as `user988052`'s, but they're definitely easier to read! The first algorithm is iterative and has a runtime of 9ms. The second algorithm is recursive and has a runtime of 16ms. Although the second solution is cleaner, the recursive calls might be slowing it down.

**First Algorithm (9ms):**

```
/** Given half a palindrome, construct the rest of the palindrome with
 * an optional string inserted in the middle. The returned string is
 * only guaranteed to be a palindrome if 'mid' is empty or a palindrome. */
public static String getPalindrome(String bin_part, String mid) {
    return bin_part + mid + (new StringBuilder(bin_part)).reverse();
}

/** Check if the specified string is a palindrome. */
public static boolean isPalindrome(String p) {
    for (int i=0; i<p.length()/2; i++)
        if (p.charAt(i) != p.charAt(p.length()-1-i))
            return false;
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] mids = {"0","1"};
    long total = 0;
    boolean longDone = false; // have the numbers with extra digits been tested

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (long i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        String bin_part = Long.toBinaryString(i);

        String bin = getPalindrome(bin_part, "");
        long dec = Long.valueOf(bin, 2);
        if (dec >= 1000000) break; // totally done

        if (isPalindrome(Long.toString(dec)))
            total += dec;

        if (!longDone) {
            for (int m=0; m<mids.length; m++)  {
                bin = getPalindrome(bin_part, mids[m]);
                dec = Long.valueOf(bin, 2);
                if (dec >= 1000000) {
                    longDone = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (isPalindrome(Long.toString(dec)))
                    total += dec;
            }
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total: " + total + " in " + (end-start) + " ms");
}
```

**Second Algorithm (16ms)**

```
public long total = 0;
public long max_value = 1000000;
public long runtime = -1;

public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i=0; i<s.length()/2; i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length()-1-i))
            return false;
    return true;
}

public void gen(String bin, boolean done) {
    if (done) { // generated a valid binary number
        // check current value and add to total if possible
        long val = Long.valueOf(bin, 2);
        if (val >= max_value)
            return;
        if (isPalindrome(Long.toString(val))) {
            total += val;
        }

        // generate next value
        gen('1' + bin + '1', true);
        gen('0' + bin + '0', false);
    } else { // generated invalid binary number (contains leading and trailing zero)
        if (Long.valueOf('1' + bin + '1', 2) < max_value) {
            gen('1' + bin + '1', true);
            gen('0' + bin + '0', false);
        }
    }
}

public void start() {
    total = 0;
    runtime = -1;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    gen("",false);
    gen("1",true);
    gen("0",false);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    runtime = end - start;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Palindromes2 p = new Palindromes2();
    p.start();
    System.out.println("Total: " + p.total + " in " + p.runtime + " ms.");
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me that these will also be palindromes in decimal

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best Python Implementation to solve this problem :

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1000000):
    bina = int(str(bin(i)).replace('0b',''))
    if(i==int(str(i)[::-1]))or(bina==int(str(bina)[::-1])):
        #print("i : "+str(i))
        #print("bina : "+str(bina))
        sum+=i
print("Sum of numbers : ",sum)
```

Comment: You can remove # in front of comments to see the individual numbers obtained during execution of program